# Change a bunch of numbers into corresponding alphabets

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, decoder

There are five types of bit encoding: 11, 10, 01, 001, 000.The corresponding message for each bit encoding is

11 -> A

10 -> B

01 -> C

001 -> D

000 -> E

The compile result will look like this：

```
Enter a sequence of bits: 01100001100110
CBEADB
```

I've wrote this but it can't work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A, B, C, D, E ;
    string code;
    cout << "Enter a sequence of bits: ";
    cin >> code;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < code.length())
    {
        if( code[i]== 1 && code[i + 1]== 1 )
        {
            cout << 'A';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if ( code[i]== 1 && code[i + 1]== 0)
        {
            cout << 'B';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if ( code[i]== 0 && code[i + 1]== 1)
        {
            cout << 'C';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if ( code[i]== 0 && code[i + 1]== 0 && code[ i + 2]== 1)
        {
            cout << 'D';
            i += 3;
        }
        else if ( code[i]== 0 && code[i + 1]== 0 && code[ i + 2]== 0)
        {
            cout << 'E';
            i += 3;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain to us in more detail why this isn't work, what you are getting, etc

Comment: `code[i]` is always a char and your are comparing it to an int.

Comment: `code[i]` will be `'0'` (0x30) or `'1'` (0x31), not 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is a String not numbers, therefore you have to check for characters. Instead of using something like `== 0`, you should be using something like `== '0'`. Also, you may want to make sure that the input has the right format and you don't run into an infinite loop (by running the `while` forever without updating `i`) or buffer overflow (aka. index out of range, by checking `code[i]` with `i >= code.length()`). You can do something like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A, B, C, D, E ;
    string code;
    cout << "Enter a sequence of bits: ";
    cin >> code;
    int i = 0;
    while (i+1 < code.length())
    {
        if( code[i]== '1' && code[i + 1]== '1' )
        {
            cout << 'A';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if ( code[i]== '1' && code[i + 1]== '0')
        {
            cout << 'B';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if ( code[i]== '0' && code[i + 1]== '1')
        {
            cout << 'C';
            i += 2;
        }
        else if (i+2 < code.length()) 
        {
            if (code[i]== '0' && code[i + 1]== '0' && code[ i + 2]== '1')
            {
                cout << 'D';
                i += 3;
                }
                else if ( code[i]== '0' && code[i + 1]== '0' && code[ i + 2]== '0')
                {
                    cout << 'E';
                    i += 3;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    return 1;
                }
        }
        else 
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (i < code.length()) {
        return 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it out [here](https://onlinegdb.com/5HmtxhoRP).

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct, you simply need to use character literals instead of int literals, for example:

```
if (code[i] == '1' && code[i + 1] == '1')
```

Digits, in strings, have codes that don't match their integral value. `'0'` is not `0`. As such, you must use `'0'` and `'1'`.